# Form submit inside each loop not working after triggering button being dynamically created

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a couple of forms that each contain a submit button.

Html example:

```
<span id="orderlines">
    <div class="productblock">
        <span class="orderlineloop">
            <input type="hidden" class="order_id_input" value="33.1159" />
            <input type="hidden" class="orderline_id_input" value="606467ae09534" />
            <span class="refreshform" id="606467ae09534">
                <form class="editorform" action="https://burrito.a2test.com/print" method="post" target="_blank">
                    <input
                        type="hidden"
                        name="json"
                        value='{"customer_id":"33","order_id":"33.1159","quantity":"1","canvas_size":"0x0","bleed":"10","safety_margin":"","dpi":"100","procheck":"n","multiple_pages":"1","product_name":"Zitzak","product_thumbnail":"https:\/\/printzelf.nl\/new\/cms\/images\/producten\/Textiel\/zitzak\/549_22ed819692c7b8fe_3.jpg","orderline":"606467ae09534"}'
                    />
                </form>
            </span>

            <div class="productblockbottom">
                <span>
                    <b>Hoe lever je jouw ontwerp aan?</b>
                    <span class="tooltippy_nostyle">
                        <img class="infosvg" src="assets/images/custom/icon_info.svg" />
                        <div class="tooltipcontent darktext tooltipcontentnone">Test</div>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <div class="productblockbtns">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                        <button class="btnstyle uploadbtn" type="button" name="button">Lever je bestanden aan <i class="icon-upload"></i></button>
                    </a>
                    <span>of</span>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                        <button class="btnstyle" type="button" name="button">Maak een ontwerp <i class="icon-design"></i></button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="unfinished editstatuscheck"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="productblock">
        <span class="orderlineloop">
            <input type="hidden" class="order_id_input" value="33.1159" />
            <input type="hidden" class="orderline_id_input" value="606467c357d7e" />
            <span class="refreshform" id="606467c357d7e">
                <form class="editorform" action="https://burrito.a2test.com/print" method="post" target="_blank">
                    <input
                        type="hidden"
                        name="json"
                        value='{"customer_id":"33","order_id":"33.1159","quantity":"1","canvas_size":"900x900","bleed":"10","safety_margin":"","dpi":"100","procheck":"y","multiple_pages":"1","product_name":"Textielframe","product_thumbnail":"https:\/\/printzelf.nl\/new\/cms\/images\/producten\/textiel_producten\/textielwand\/1288_9936468fbe050be8_1.jpg","orderline":"606467c357d7e"}'
                    />
                </form>
            </span>

            <div class="productblockbottom">
                <span>
                    <b>Hoe lever je jouw ontwerp aan?</b>
                    <span class="tooltippy_nostyle">
                        <img class="infosvg" src="assets/images/custom/icon_info.svg" />
                        <div class="tooltipcontent darktext tooltipcontentnone">Test</div>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <div class="productblockbtns">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                        <button class="btnstyle uploadbtn" type="button" name="button">Lever je bestanden aan <i class="icon-upload"></i></button>
                    </a>
                    <span>of</span>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                        <button class="btnstyle" type="button" name="button">Maak een ontwerp <i class="icon-design"></i></button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="unfinished editstatuscheck"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</span>
```

I submit every form like this:

```
$( ".uploadbtn" ).each(function() {
    var form = $(this).closest('.productblock').find('.editorform');
    $(this).click(function() {
        form.submit();
    });
});
```

This used to work, but now I changed it so that the button that triggers the form submit is generated dynamically (at the moment every 2 seconds). And now the button won't submit anymore.

This is the code that "refreshes" all submit buttons:

```
// Function below executes every 2 seconds
var editorcheck = function() {
    // Post order id to editorcheck.php
    order_id = $('.order_id_input').val();
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:"payprocess/editorcheck.php",
        data:({order_id: order_id}),
        success:function(data){
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            // Loop json result from editorcheck.php
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                var status = obj[i].edit_status;
                var orderline = obj[i].orderline;
                // Loop all elements with class .orderlineloop
                $(".orderlineloop").each(function(i) {
                    // If the returned status == finished
                    if(obj[i].edit_status == 'finished'){
                        if($(this).find('.orderline_id_input').val() == obj[i].orderline){
                            $(this).find('.productblockbottom').empty().append('<div class="finishedblock"><span><b>Je ontwerp is ontvangen</b>  <img class="feedbacksvg" src="assets/images/custom/icon_good.svg"></span> <a href="#" title="Verwijderen"><i class="icon-trash deletedesign"></i></a></div>');
                        }
                    }else if(obj[i].edit_status == 'unfinished'){
                        // Else if status == unfinished
                        $(this).find('.productblockbottom').empty().append('<span><b>Hoe lever je jouw ontwerp aan?</b>  <span class="tooltippy_nostyle"><img class="infosvg" src="assets/images/custom/icon_info.svg"><div class="tooltipcontent darktext tooltipcontentnone">Test</div></span></span>'
                        +'<div class="productblockbtns">'
                        +'<a href="javascript:void(0);"><button class="btnstyle uploadbtn" type="button" name="button">Lever je bestanden aan <i class="icon-upload"></i></button></a>'
                        +'<span>of</span>'
                        +'<a href="javascript:void(0);"><button class="btnstyle" type="button" name="button">Maak een ontwerp <i class="icon-design"></i></button></a>'
                        +'</div>');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
var interval = 2000;
setInterval(editorcheck, interval);
```

This is the part where the buttons get replaced:

```
}else if(obj[i].edit_status == 'unfinished'){
    // Else if status == unfinished
    $(this).find('.productblockbottom').empty().append('<span><b>Hoe lever je jouw ontwerp aan?</b>  <span class="tooltippy_nostyle"><img class="infosvg" src="assets/images/custom/icon_info.svg"><div class="tooltipcontent darktext tooltipcontentnone">Test</div></span></span>'
    +'<div class="productblockbtns">'
    +'<a href="javascript:void(0);"><button class="btnstyle uploadbtn" type="button" name="button">Lever je bestanden aan <i class="icon-upload"></i></button></a>'
    +'<span>of</span>'
    +'<a href="javascript:void(0);"><button class="btnstyle" type="button" name="button">Maak een ontwerp <i class="icon-design"></i></button></a>'
    +'</div>');
}
```

I was thinking that my `each` loop can't find the buttons anymore since they have been replaced/dynamically created. So I looked for something like `.on()` for the `each` function, but I see that doesn't exist.

So I tried starting from an element higher in the DOM hierarchy, one that doesn't get replaced and from there find the button like this:

```
$( "body .uploadbtn" ).each(function() {
    var form = $(this).closest('.productblock').find('.editorform');
    $(this).click(function() {
        form.submit();
    });
});
```

But this also doesn't work. What can I do?

I also tried not putting the trigger on `uploadbtn` but on an element that never refreshes and from there select the `uploadbtn`:

```
$( ".orderlineloop" ).each(function() {
    var submitbutton = $(this).find('.uploadbtn');
    var form = $(this).find('.editorform');
    $(submitbutton).click(function() {
        form.submit();
    });
});
```

But again this doesn't work. I can only submit the button once if I click fast (before the function replaces the button).

Comment: It might be best to lower the amount of code down to the code that you changed and that broke the program. Everything else that worked before and after is most likely irrelevant. It will be much easier to read.

Comment: @Ivan86 I removed some irrelevant HTML

Comment: The submit button is created after the DOM loaded?

Comment: @Zander No it is there from the beginning. But keeps getting reloaded every 2 seconds. (emptied and appended). So submit button is new in the DOM every 2 seconds but on pageload there already is a button.

Comment: @twan maybe, try to make something like `$("body").on("click", "yourButton", function() {...})` as it's getting "renewed/created", it doesn't triggers the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For dynamically added elements you need to use event delegation with the `.on()` method, so you were on the right track.

This should work for you:

```
$(document).on('click', '.uploadbtn', function () {                
   var form = $(this).closest('.productblockbottom').siblings('.refreshform').find('.editorform');
   form.submit();
});
```

**Edit:** Added OP solution for finding the form element from comment below.

Comment: Thanks! I had to change form line a bit to this: `var form = $(this).closest('.productblockbottom').siblings('.refreshform').find('.editorform');` but now it works.